# Why aren't the bottom 3 dropdown-items working?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.6 and cannot figure out why the bottom 3 dropdown-items are not working. When I switch the order of the items the results stay the same, only the top 2 items work.

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  console.log(el);
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styleNew6.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/popup.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/omo2zlt.css">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="fav.png">

<!-- MENU -->
<div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-10 col-xs-9">
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="133px" data-aos="fade-in" data-aos-duration="2000" data-aos-delay="250"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
  <div class="dropdown show justify-content-end" data-aos="fade-in" data-aos-duration="2000" data-aos-delay="250">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <div class="bar1">_</div>
        <div class="bar2">_</div>
        <div class="bar3">_</div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
      <a href="#about" class="dropdown-item">About</a><br><br>
      <a href="#EPK" class="dropdown-item">EPK</a><br><br>
      <a href="#service" class="dropdown-item">Services</a><br><br>
      <a href="#clients" class="dropdown-item">Clients</a><br><br>
      <a href="#contact" class="dropdown-item">Contact</a><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've added CDN library assets to your snippet. Please revise further to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I mocked up that function and all the dropdown elements seem to behave the same. Please revise further to demonstrate.